# Is there a non-circular definition of consciousness?

Tags: consciousness, definitions

All the definitions of consciousness I have come across seem to be circular. It is usually defined to be "experience", or "something that it is like to be". But that is circular. So, has anyone defined consciousness in a non-circular way? Or, is consciousness simply an undefined term? Perhaps there is simply no formal definition of consciousness.

Comment: It's the thing you have to have to ask questions like this one.

Comment: Any definition of a mental thing requires mental language, just like any definition of a moral thing requires moral language and any definition of a physical thing requires physical language.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Bootstrapping: it's not just a good idea, it's the law.

Comment: @user107952 "*definition of consciousness*" You don't define things. You define the words we use to refer to things. Consciousness is what it is. It does not need any definition.

Comment: In fact, there are few circular definitions of consciousness. [I've posted my own, which is purely circular, clarifying that it is barely based on another](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94639/is-conscious-thought-ever-necessary/94647#94647), which is not integrally circular.

Comment: @Speakpigeon, however, there is a thread in philosophy going back to Aristotle that does say you define things rather than words. I don't agree with it, but it's a respectable philosophical position.